# openldap initial setup, olcRootDN does not have permissions to update

Tags: openldap

educating myself with openldap. I thought that olcRootDN would have admin priviledges by default, but that does not seem to be the case. Is it normal to have to setup olcAccess rules for olcRootDN?

Thanks.

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}mdb
olcDbDirectory: /usr/local/var/openldap-data
olcSuffix: dc=EXAMPLE,dc=COM
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=EXAMPLE,dc=COM
olcRootPW:: c2VjcmV0
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
structuralObjectClass: olcMdbConfig
entryUUID: 3b3e5552-c11d-4e20-a61a-ad82d9f18e22
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20190221042051Z
entryCSN: 20190221042051.752732Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20190221042051Z

bash-4.4#
bash-4.4#
bash-4.4# ldapwhoami -D cn=Manager,dc=EXAMPLE,dc=COM -W -H ldaps://ldap.EXAMPLE.COM
Enter LDAP Password:
dn:cn=Manager,dc=EXAMPLE,dc=COM
bash-4.4#
bash-4.4#
bash-4.4#
bash-4.4#
bash-4.4# ldapmodify -D cn=Manager,dc=EXAMPLE,dc=COM -H ldaps://ldap.EXAMPLE.COM -f /etc/openldap/kerberos_index.ldif -W
Enter LDAP Password:
modifying entry "olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)
```

Comment: The Root DN is for the server itself to use. You should not use it yourself in any way. For example, it bypasses the password policy overlay. Create an admin user or group and give it the required privileges.

Comment: Pertinent server log does seem to indicate that the olcRootDN does not have appropriate access: